# Bulk File Processing in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a perl program which is taking huge time.Can someone suggest the option for tuning.
Requirement
Perl program doing some file processing after database retrieval and further processing required based on values present in database. So the logic is

```
my $sql="select KEY,VALUE from TABLEA";    
 my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute;
while ( my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array( ) ) {
        $tagdata{@row[0]} = @row[1];
}
```

TABLEA contains 3 million rows. Now in perl program after so many file processing, I need to find the key for a given value. The key is unique but the value is not.
So key is found out by following logic.

```
my @keysfind = grep { $tagdata{$_} eq $value } keys %tagdata;
            foreach (@keysfind)
            {
```

and based on`@keysfind` the processing is done. This process is taking huge time as this(finding the key) is run in a loop (0.1 million times).
The options which i tried are
1) Use  `fetchall_hashref` instead of `fetchrow_array`. Though it was little faster but not much.
2) Instead of having hash, move all these operations into database i.e. fetch the key based on value but the problem is that this value fetching loop runs 0.1 million times which means it will have these number of database calls though the query will be straightforward.

Can anyone suggest a better approach to handle this.

Comment: I doubt you can outperform a database query by *looping* over millions of values. However: when optimizing, write both solutions, then benchmark. Performance is never obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probably best solution is to delegate finding the keys to the database, as shown in chorobas answer.

For academic purposes only, here is a way to find matching keys in constant time without using the database. All we need is a reverse hash that maps values to an array of keys:

```
my %tagdata;
my %reverse_tagdata;
my $sth = $dbh->prepare('select KEY,VALUE from TABLEA');
$sth->execute;
while ( my ($key, $value) = $sth->fetchrow_array ) {
    $tagdata{$key} = $value;
    push @{ $reverse_tagdata{$value} }, $key; # add key to matching values
}

...;

my $value = ...;
my @found_keys = @{ $reverse_tagdata{$value} }; # one simple hash lookup
for my $key (@found_keys) { 
  ...;
}
```

Comment: I changed to code to use reverse hash instead of grep and its much faster. Thanks for this. Alternatively I have moved my business logic to database and doing performance evaluations on both the options.

Answer (score 4):

If you can, let the database do the hard work:

```
my $sql = 'select KEY, VALUE from TABLEA where VALUE = ?';    
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute($value);
```